# Copy a file to Multiple folders Linux

Tags: linux, copy

I am in a directory /xyz . In this /xyz directory there are multiple folders of students in alphabetically stored with their names. 
so I have a file value.txt which i want to copy to all folders of students who have their names beginning with A, B, C, D uptil R.

For example, in /xyz i have the following directories:

/amy

/brandon

/charles

/gina

/robert

/mike

/peter

/lily

I want to copy value.txt to all folders who have names beginning from A to R that is in

/amy

/brandon

/charles

/gina

/robert

Thanks
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to create a script, either in perl, php or shell.

Comment: I am new to this.
What kind of shell script can I make to do this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
for dirname in $(ls -d [a-r]*)
do
    cp value.txt ${dirname}/
done
```

Comment: regex pattern should be [a-R] otherwise it fails for capital R.

Comment: @mrcl: `[a-R]` is not a valid regex. Looking the directories in the question I kept it that way. Though if it is desired in uppercase, regex would be `ls -d [a-rA-R]*`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
for s in [a-r]*; do cp file.text $s; done
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other side, if let say the number of letters you want to exclude  will make the script less complicated , then you  can do the following:

```
 [^YZ]*
```

This [^YZ]  pattern will  match any character except Y or Z - bash manual has more details . [Read ths](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following lines to a file e.g.: cpFile2Dirs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dList=`ls -d */`

for d in $dList;
do
    if [[ $d == [a-rA-R]* ]];
    then
        cp $1 $d
    fi

done
```

which should sit in the directory you are currently working on.

then execute

```
bash cpFile2Dirs.sh value.txt
```

this will copy the file value.txt to all directories starting with a/A up to r/R, as defined in the if statement. You can change that as you like.

You can also set execution permission to your script

```
chmod +x cpFile2Dirs.sh
```

then you don't need to run `bash copyValues.sh value.txt`, but simply

```
./cpFile2Dirs.sh value.txt
```

Hope it helps.